# React no muestra el primer valor en un array utilizando keydown

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, react-hooks, keypressevent

Tengo una función que debería tomar las letras introducidas por el teclado y meterlas en un array para hacer la mecánica de un juego de "ahorcado" en React.

El problema es que siempre el primer carácter que introduzco no lo "guarda" (cabe mencionar que mi código está en codepen).

Esta es mi función, ¿alguien podría ayudarme? No sé por qué no está capturando el primer valor. Por si quieren ver el codepen, este es el link: https://codepen.io/uriel-gomez-raga/full/ZEadObG

```javascript
useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {

        const { keyCode, key } = event;
        const letter = (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) ? key.toLowerCase() : undefined;
        if (letter) {
            if (word.includes(letter)) {
                if (!correct.includes(letter)) {
                    setCorrect(current => [...current, letter])
                } else {
                    console.log("ya escogiste esa letra")
                }
            } else {
                if (!wrong.includes(letter)) {
                    setWrong(current => [...current, letter]);
                } else {
                    console.log("ya te quivocaste con esa letra")
                }

            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
}, [correct, wrong])
```

Comment: Veo que la letra se guarda en el estado `correct`. ¿Entonces cuál sería el problema?

Comment: Cuando accedo a la información, la primera letra jamás la toma. Por ejemplo, tengo otro componente que muestra el estado correct, y jamás toma el primer resultado.

Comment: La pregunta necesita mas desarrollo, si pudieras describir dónde y como pretendes acceder a la información en el otro componente, que es donde según tus comentarios no toma el primer resultado.

Comment: Aquí está el código que toma la parte de correct para mostrar la información; PERO ESE NO ES EL PROBLEMA. 

const Screen = ({pokemon, reveal, correct}) => {  
  return(
    <div> 
      <img src={pokemon?.sprites?.other.dream_world.front_default} 
        className={ reveal ? "pokemonImg": "pokemonHide"}
        />
      <h3> {correct} </h3>
    </div>
  )  
}

Lo que mi función que puse en el comentario principal no hace, es que no guarda la primera letra que se teclea. ESO ES LO QUE NO HACE